# Is there a way to send a series of jobs to rabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, distributed-computing, json-rpc

I have `jobs`named `A, B, C, D`. Job `B` has to start after job `A` finished. So the order of jobs should look like this `A->B->C->D`.

I want to scale number of workers for `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` indepently. Is there a way to implement this using `RabbitMQ`, I am basically looking for a way to create a `series` of `jobs`.

My current design looks like this:

1. The `caller` process creates `seriesOfJobs`: array of `JSON`s that describe jobs `A,B,C,D` using `JSON-RPC` protocol
2. The `caller` sends the `seriesOfJobs` to a `seriesManager`(separate process) via `RabbitMQ` `RPC` and awaits callback on `mainCallbackQueue`
3. The `seriesManager` parses `seriesOfJobs` sends job `A` to a`workerA`(separate process) via `RabbitMQ` `RPC` and awaits callback on `callbackQueueA`
4. `workerA` performs job `A` and notifies `seriesManager` via `callbackQueueA`
5. `seriesManager` gets callback from `callbackQueueA` and sends job `B` to worker and awaits callback, then the same for job `C`, then the same for job `D`
6. `seriesManager` knows that it jobs `A,B,C,D` finished - it notifies `caller` via `mainCallbackQueue`

I am using the concept of `RPC` as described here [RabbitMQ RPC tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

*(Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment, so this may be a somewhat lacking answer as I can't clarify requirements, though I'll try and edit it to stick to what's needed)*

Is there an absolute need for the `seriesManager` to be present?

It may be more logical to have `workerA` create job `B` for `workerB` and so on and so forth rather than consistently calling back to a central hub.

In which case your current design would change to:

1. `caller` creates `seriesOfJobs`.
2. `caller` sends `seriesOfJobs` to `workerA`.
3. `workerA` performs job `A` and sends remaining `seriesOfJobs` to `workerB`.
4. `workerB` performs job `B` and sends remaining `seriesOfJobs` to `workerC`.
5. `workerC` performs job `C` and sends remaining `seriesOfJobs` to `workerD`.
6. `workerD` performs job `D` and notifies `caller` via `mainCallbackQueue`.

I would regard that a "simpler way" seeing as it takes that nasty central hub out of the equation.

Comment: The design you suggested is similar to the current one(in the project I am working on). The central hub approach has two advantages for me: 1) all the `smarts` are in one place, `workers` are just dumb `rpc` request/response endpoints 2) If job `B` fails the central hub can abort jobs `C/D` and notify the `caller`

Comment: I can export all the `smarts` to a library that `workers` will use...I am not experienced enough to tell which approach is better :)

Comment: Also the central hub enables not only `series` but also `parallel` - but I admit it introduces a lot of complexity (additional queues for callbacks and so on..)

Comment: Workers being dumb is usually a good choice as, more than anything, it makes them nice and reusable, though I'd see the extra complication in their functions to be a good trade off for removing the `seriesManager`. Personally, however, I can't see a simpler way to achieve what you want without the removal of that, which as you say can provide some benefits.

Comment: I realised that with `seriesOfJobs` and callback, a smart `caller` can implement also `parallel` and other async patterns. I am getting more and more convinced of this `smart-worker` approach